# Magento 1.7.0.2 SUPEE-6788

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to patch a Magento 1.7.0.2 with the

PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-10-27-12-00-16.sh

I have solved several line ending problems and missing .htaccess.sample ...

But these file cannot be patched:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file     
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej

patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 410.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 474.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file     
lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php.rej
```

I downloaded a fresh Magento 1.7.0.2 copy (from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download)
and tried to apply the patch on it but also
failed.

Checked the lines mentioned on CLI (like FAILED at 131)
but I did not found anything suspicious.

Also it did not write any .rej files

Any advise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: Backup the site

step 2: apply all previous patches for your site version

step 3: apply the latest patch

step 4:  you should get an error - download Magento 1.7.0.2 and upload the files it says it fails.

e.g. upload the db.php file to the correct directory. (first download your site's version of that file as a backup)

step 5: reapply the patch - it should work.

Comment: Yes, there was a previous patch missing. Thanks.